# Binding ViewModel to multiple windows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm re-writing my windows forms project that does scoring for sheep shearing events (don't ask, its a huge sport in New Zealand) from vbnet to wpf c# and have struck a problem that I can't seem to overcome.

I have two windows. One is the source window where you type things in (like the current event name), and the other window will display this information in a flash way for projection onto a screen (so will be on a second monitor) along with some other data coming in via XML over the network. I have set it up as MVVM with a ViewModel and a Model as separate projects.

On my Main window, I can bind controls fine and if I type in one text box it immediately appears in another text box if it is bound to the same thing.
However, on a second window, I have bound a control to the same thing and it is not updating.

I've been going around in circles on this for a week, every example on the net shows how to do it on One window which I have got working fine, but there is a lack of two window examples.

Here is what I have...

This is in my ViewModel project

```
namespace SheepViewModel
{
public class SheepViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged


{
    private string _CurrentEventName;
    static SheepViewModel _details;

    public string CurrentEventName
    {
        get { return _CurrentEventName; }
        set
        {
            _CurrentEventName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentEventName");
        }
    }

    public static SheepViewModel GetDetails()
    {
        if (_details == null)
            _details = new SheepViewModel();
        return _details;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
            }     
    }
}
```

Then I have a main window, there is no real code behind other than a line to open a second window which we will get to...

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        ScoreScreen SW = new ScoreScreen();
        SW.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Sheep_Score_3._1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SheepViewModel;assembly=SheepViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="433.689" Width="941.194">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:SheepViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
<TextBox x:Name="CurrentEventName" Height="23" Margin="131.01,163.013,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="327.151" Text="{Binding CurrentEventName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentEventName, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="39.605,0,0,108.567" Height="49.111" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="399" />
</Grid>
```

The above code all works fine, if I type text in the first textbox it appears in the second text box. If I put a console.writeline in the notify part then I can see it hitting it and updating.

Now I add a second window, setup exactly the same way...

```
<Window x:Class="Sheep_Score_3._1.ScoreScreen"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SheepViewModel;assembly=SheepViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ScoreScreen" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:SheepViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="79.374,116.672,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding CurrentEventName, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Again, no real code behind in this.

The strange thing, is if I make this control two way and type in it, I can see it hitting the same notify section, but it is not updating the other window.

I'm not sure what I am missing here so any help in pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because *both windows must share the exact same instance of the ViewModel*.

All your properties are *instance properties*, like

```
public string CurrentEventName { get { // snip
```

and therefore all values are distinct to each instance.  You're creating **two** instances, one for each window.

```
<Window x:Class="Sheep_Score_3._1.MainWindow"
    xmlns:blah="http://inurxamlskippinurschemas.org">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:SheepViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

That's one instance, and here's the other

```
<Window x:Class="Sheep_Score_3._1.ScoreScreen"
        xmlns:blah="http://yaddayaddawhocares.derp">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:SheepViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Remember, xaml is just markup that is *deserialized* into an object graph.  You've got two different markup files, they contain distinct instances of everything described within them.

There's nothing wrong with this, and nothing wrong with having a view model with instance properties.  In fact, that's the preferred way over using statics and static bindings.

The answer is luckily simple.  You need to hand **both windows** the **same instance** of your view model.

First, remove all the `<Window.DataContext>` nonsense from both of your windows.  That's not for you.  Now, simply change your constructor to

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var viewModel = new SheepViewModel();
    ScoreScreen SW = new ScoreScreen();
    SW.DataContext = viewModel;
    SW.Show();
    InitializeComponent();
    //NOTICE!  After Init is called!
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

And you're done.

Comment: Thankyou thankyou thankyou, this nailed it.
This makes perfect sense, I had a feeling they were two separate instances but coming from a vb background I wasn't sure how to link them like this.

Comment: Hahahaha! +1 just for "yaddayaddawhocares.derp"

Comment: @TobyMills if you're not sure about instances, you can always use Object IDs to track them.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/03/04/make-object-id/ Good luck with the shearing!  Oh, and if you shout me out when you premiere your rewrite, that would be ***super awesome***.

Comment: Will do @Will the competition will be broadcast here in 5 weeks...
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Golden+shears+TV&ie=&oe=

Comment: Since specifying the DataContext in the XAML file would make Visual Studio designer able to offer the members of the DataContext in IntelliSense, you could say `SW.DataContext = DataContex`, and leave the `<Window.DataContext>` nonsense in the MainWindow and specify `d:DataContext` attribute for the other window in XAML. Or just specify `d:DataContext` in both windows, but the constructor should remain as @Will wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that each window is creating its own instance of the ViewModel.  You could try the following:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SheepViewModel svm = new SheepViewModel();
    this.DataContext = svm;

    ScoreScreen SW = new ScoreScreen();
    SW.DataContext = svm;
    SW.Show();        
}
```

Comment: Not sure if the DataContext from xaml is set within InitializeComponent, so this.DataContext may be null at this time.

Comment: You can set the datacontext after initialize.

Comment: Eh, wasn't sure, so I took a minute to verify it... DataContext is filled after InitializeComponent but not before, so your original would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your viewmodel defines a static method to get a single instance but you do not use it to instantiate it. Currently your viewmodel is being created with the default constructor which means the two windows will have separate copies.

Create your viewmodel in the code behind either below InitializeComponent or in the OnNavigatedToEvent.

Here's some code to explain further:

define a ViewModel property like so in both windows

```
property SheepViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

Then your constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = SheepViewModel.GetDetails(); // include this line
    ScoreScreen SW = new ScoreScreen();
    SW.Show();
}
```

also remove the

```
<vm:SheepViewModel/>
```

from the xaml as it's not required.

Comment: That's not right.  He's already got a property on both of his windows that is designed for his view model--Window.DataContext.

Comment: read my answer again I state that its calling the default constructor so its not working as OP intended he has written a static method to get the instance I merely showed him how to use it.

Comment: Read my comment again-you said he should 'define a ViewModel property like so in both windows' which is spectacularly incorrect.  The view model goes in `DataContext`, not some random property.

Comment: ViewModel is not a random property its whats used with Binding and x:Bind on WinRT since release of Win 10. The are some great articles on msdn like Data Binding In Depth you might find interesting.

Comment: Aaah, I see the confusion... OP's application is plain old WPF, which means bindings work with the DataContext.  Your example may be valid in UWPs but it isn't valid here--check his code, he's using Bindings.  I'd be dickish and suggest you go brush up on ancient Windows Presentation Foundation docs, but why bother?  Bind is the future!

Comment: it still works with Binding in UWP just in a slight roundabout fashion ie collectionviewsource etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the ViewModel as an application resource

```
<Application.Resources>
    <VM:ViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModel" />
    ....
</Application.Resources>
```

then in the each window you call it like this

```
DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"
```

I'm still new to this concept, and I'm not sure if this is optimal. It works though!